# AVPlayer with Equalizer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am developing an iOS app which require to play audio from soundcloud. I can successfully play audio using AVPlayer with live audio stream. 
Now, I want to set equalizer for AVPlayer so, user can manage output sound for this.

I search for this but all documents are so complicated.

So, can anyone please guide me regarding this? So, I can set equalizer effect for this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think AVPlayer is not support for Equalizer Effect, for this you need to apply bands for all audio units but by using   STKAudioPlayer u can achieve it easily. refer following link it will help you.

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

Comment: Thanks. I need to show player' detail on lock screen, Everything is already setup just one thing pending is Equilizer . Still, I will look into code and update you.

Comment: most of all properties of audioplayer will achieve throgh this player

Comment: Ok I just downloaded it. Looking into it.

Comment: I just edit question. I need to get effect manager just like image.But I think this library not providing this.

Comment: you need to design your view like that , based upon that frequency change you cna effect your equalizer

Comment: you need to give frequencies like this at time of player initialization

Comment: self.myPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:(STKAudioPlayerOptions)
                     {
                         
                         .enableVolumeMixer = YES,
                         
                         .equalizerBandFrequencies = {31, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000}
                     }];

Comment: [self.myPlayer play: [url absoluteString]];

Comment: you can set gainvalues  for all bands like this, here i set one value for all bands u can set different gainvalues for diffrent bands

Comment: -(void)setBandValue:(float)gainValue forPlayer:(STKAudioPlayer *)palyer {
    
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:0];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:1];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:2];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:3];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:4];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:5];

Comment: [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:6];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:7];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:8];
    [palyer setGain:gainValue forEqualizerBand:9];
}

Comment: I integrate your code. But when I try to set Gain player stopped playing. I need to play again. And thanks, this effect work but with this little issue.

Comment: Can we play video with STKAudioPlayer?

Comment: i think it is for only Audio

Comment: The bad thing about StreamingKit is that it doesn't support m4a files.